# Transferring a JPEG file between processes in C

Tags: c, image, jpeg, fwrite, fread

I'm writing a server with a client and I'm having issues transferring images. I tried to `fread` the file on a buffer, to send the buffer to the client and to `fwrite` the buffer on a new file and it worked! Now it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why, when I check the new file, my image opener says that it's impossible to open the JPEG file etc.
My reading code:

```
int fd=open(pathname, O_RDONLY, 0666);
struct stat fileStat;
if(fstat(fd,&fileStat) < 0)   
{ 
    perror("\nfilestat\n");
    exit(-1);
}


int fileSize=(int)fileStat.st_size; 
//printf("File Size: \t\t%d bytes\n",fileSize);


FILE *f=fdopen(fd, "rb");
if(f==NULL)
{
    perror("\nfopen\n");
    exit(-1);
}

void *buf=malloc(fileSize);
if(buf==NULL)
{
    perror("\nmalloc\n");
    return -1;
}

int FR=fread(buf, fileSize, 1, f);

if(FR<0)
{
    perror("\nfread\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Then I write the body on my server message:

```
punt+=sprintf(punt, "%s\r\n", (char *)buf);
```

And after the client has extracted it from the received message, I fwrite it on a new file:

```
char *clientfile="./qui.jpg";               
int fdbis=open(clientfile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);

if(fdbis<=0)
{
    perror("\nopen 2\n");
    exit(-1);
}               

FILE *fbis=fdopen(fdbis, "wb");
if(fbis==NULL)
{
    perror("fdopen");
    exit(-1);
}


int WR=fwrite((void*)buf, strlen(buf), 1, fbis);
if(WR<=0)
{
    perror("\nfwrite\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

I'm not pasting my server-client code because the code above doesn't work either on a test program without sending/receiving and without string extraction, so the problem has to be in it.

I'm programming in C, with a Posix system, and compiling with gcc.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The data in `buf` is *not* a valid C string. So you can't use `sprintf` or `strlen` on `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

Since a jpeg file is binary, you cannot use string function to manipulate it.
`strlen(buf)` will return the length till the first null termination.

use `memcpy`.

Comment: I switched to memcpy some time ago, it worked and now it doesn' go again,  it seems the fwrite write less bytes than needed and requested.